# Dimension-free sample complexity for estimating Gaussian covariance

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, random-matrices

(also [asked on math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4169322/estimate-nearly-singular-gaussian-covariance-matrix), with no answers)

Suppose I have $m$ samples drawn from a Gaussian in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and need sample covariance $\Sigma_m$ to be $\epsilon$-close to true covariance $\Sigma$:

$$E\|\Sigma_m-\Sigma\| \le \epsilon \|\Sigma\|$$

Vershynin ([High-Dimensional Probability](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf) Remark 5.6.3) gives the following sample requirement for *arbitrary* distribution in terms of intrinsic dimension $r=\text{tr}\ \Sigma/\|\Sigma\|$
$$m \approx \epsilon^{-2} r \log n$$

Is there a tighter bound for the Gaussian case? In particular, I'm wondering if $\log n$ term can be dropped

A simulation is here, it seems if we keep intrinsic dimensionality fixed, and sample size fixed, the error doesn't grow with dimensions.

[image]

[notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/mathse-gaussian-sample-error.nb)

Comment: If you want a bound that is as tight as possible, you certainly need to use the peculiarities of the Gaussian case. Did you have a look into the Wishart distribution and how it concentrates around its mean ? I do not believe that you can get rid of the dimension.

Comment: For a Gaussian with covariance a multiple of identity, you can drop the $\log n$ part, so the sample complexity becomes dependent only on the intrinsic dimension $r$ and not on the ambient dimension $n$

Comment: Sure. For your question to be clearer, it might be better to state that dimension-free in your question refers to the ambient space and not the intrinsic dimension. Note also that the case you are referring to is extremely restrictive. What set of matrices $\Sigma$ do you want to consider ?

Comment: I agree terminology could be ambiguous. I first saw "dimension-free" used in this way in Nick Harvey's notes https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~nickhar/W12/Lecture15Notes.pdf . Without context perhaps a better way would have been to say "depending on effective dimension, independent of ambient dimension".

Comment: The most interesting result would be a tight bound for unrestricted $\Sigma$, but special cases might be interesting too

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, doesn't Vershynin's Theorem 9.2.4 address this?

Comment: good catch....that seems to be the case [Theorem 9.2.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coQrg.png)