# Dimension-free sample complexity for the inverse of Gaussian sample covariance?

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, random-matrices

Suppose I have $m$ samples drawn from a Gaussian in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and need the inverse of the sample covariance $\Sigma_m^{-1}$ to be $\varepsilon$-close to true inverse covariance $\Sigma^{-1}$ (in expectation or (preferably) with high probability):

$$\|\Sigma^{-1}_m-\Sigma^{-1}\| \le \varepsilon \|\Sigma^{-1}\|$$

For the sample covariance it is [known](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/395098/dimension-free-sample-complexity-for-estimating-gaussian-covariance) that
$$\|\Sigma_m-\Sigma\| \le \varepsilon \|\Sigma\|$$
can be achieved with $r=\operatorname{tr} \Sigma/\|\Sigma\|$ (the intrinsic dimension)
$$m \approx \varepsilon^{-2} r$$

I wonder if there is anything similar for the inverse covariance?

Comment: $\Sigma_m^{-1}-\Sigma^{-1}=\Sigma^{-1}(\Sigma-\Sigma_m)\Sigma_m^{-1}$ gives a rough bound that may be sufficient for some problems.